# Script does not work for jQuery Mobile 1.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This code works just as I want it, but when I click the [jQuery Mobile 1.3 checkbox at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/234/) then it looks/behaves otherwise.  What to do?

```
<input type="radio" name="fotoorurl" id="Package_1" checked />
<input type="radio" name="fotoorurl" id="Package_2" />

<div class="package_extension1"> div 1 </div>  
<div class="package_extension2"> div 2 </div>  

$(".package_extension2").hide(); // namn på div

$("#Package_1").click(function(){ // package_1 är ID på checkbox
     $(".package_extension1").show(); // namn på div
     $(".package_extension2").hide(); // namn på div
});


$("#Package_2").click(function(){ // package_2 är ID på checkbox
     $(".package_extension2").show(); // namn på div
     $(".package_extension1").hide(); // namn på div
});
```

Comment: Please, try to translate the code comments to English when asking for help on an international community.

Answer (score 0):

You should consume the [jQuery Mobile Introduction](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/intro/) to get familiar with it.

```
<div data-role="page">
<div id="content" data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>Package:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="p-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-1">Package 1</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="p-2" />
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Package 2</label>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="package_extension1"> div 1 </div>  
        <div class="package_extension2"> div 2 </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/239/

Answer (score 0):

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css

line no : 2359

overide these properties

```
.ui-checkbox input, .ui-radio input {
  height: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  outline: 0 none !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
```

}